# What is the difference between the meaning of 0x and \x in Python hex strings?

Tags: python, hex

I'm doing some binary operations which are often shown as hex-es. I have seen both the `0x` and `\x` as prefixes.

In which case is which used?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`0x` is used for literal numbers. `"\x"` is used inside strings to represent a character

```
>>> 0x41
65
>>> "\x41"
'A'

>>> "\x01" # a non printable character
'\x01'
```

Comment: @mgilson, for output they are used for non-printing characters. But they can represent any character in a literal string.

Comment: So the `"\x"` notation isn't in any way connected with hex numbers?

Comment: @Alan, the 2 digits following the \x are hex. so `"\x41" == chr(65)`

Comment: So the "\x" notation, in case of a non printable character, shows one byte of raw binary data in form of two hex numbers?

Comment: 0x are hexadecimal (base 16)

Answer (score -3):

0x follows number, means HEX number

\x follows number, means HEX ascii characters

check it here:
[ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)