# python regex: how to remove hex dec characters from string

Tags: python, regex

```
text="\xe2\x80\x94"
print re.sub(r'(\\(?<=\\)x[a-z0-9]{2})+',"replacement_text",text)
```

output is `—`

how can I handle the hex decimal characters in this situation?

Comment: Your input doesn't *have* backslashes. It has 3 bytes, the UTF-8 encoding for U+2014 EM DASH.

Comment: Dude, `text` **is not** literally `\xe2\x80\x94`. `\x` is a special character that tells Python that next two characters will be interpreted as hex digits for some character code.

Answer (score 2):

Your input doesn't *have* backslashes. It has 3 bytes, the UTF-8 encoding for the [U+2014 EM DASH](https://codepoints.net/U+2014) character:

```
>>> text = "\xe2\x80\x94"
>>> len(text)
3
>>> text[0]
'\xe2'
>>> text.decode('utf8')
u'\u2014'
>>> print text.decode('utf8')
—
```

You either need to match those UTF-8 bytes directly, or decode from UTF-8 to `unicode` and match the codepoint. The latter is preferable; always try to deal with text as Unicode to simplify how many characters you have to transform at a time.

Also note that Python's `repr()` output (which is used impliciltly when echoing in the interactive interpreter or when printing lists, dicts or other containers) uses `\xhh` escape sequences to represent any non-printable character. For UTF-8 strings, that includes anything outside the ASCII range. You could just replace anything outside that range with:

```
re.sub(r'[\x80-\xff]+', "replacement_text", text)
```

Take into account that this'll match *multiple* UTF-8-encoded characters in a row, and replace these together as a group!

Answer (score 0):

Your input is in hex, not an actual "\xe2\x80\x94".
\x is just the way to say that the following characters should be interpreted in hex.

This was explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903192/meaning-of-0x-and-x-in-python-hex-strings).