# Getting rid of hex using regex

Tags: python, regex, hex

I'm trying to delete some hex (such as `\xc3`) from strings of text.
I plan to use regular expressions to help get rid of those.
Here is my code:

```
import re
tweet = 'b"[/Very seldom~ will someone enter your life] to question\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa6"'    
tweet1 = re.sub(r'\\x[a-f0-9]{2}', '', tweet)
print(tweet1)
```

However, instead of deleting the output I actually get  the encoded version of hex. Here is my output:

```
b"[/Very seldom~ will someone enter your life] to questionÃ¢â¬Â¦ "
```

Does somebody know how I can get rid of those hex strings?... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tweet1.decode('ascii','ignore')` after applying the regex.

Comment: I get this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. Should I encode instead?

Comment: Yes. `tweet1.encode('ascii','ignore')`. The decode function has been removed in python 3.x. My bad, although you should mention that this is a python 3.x question in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import re
import string

tweet = 'b"[/Very seldom~ will someone enter your life] to question\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa6"'    
tweet1 = re.sub(r'[^\w\s{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '', tweet)
print(tweet1)
```

Output:

```
b"[Very seldom~ will someone enter your life] to question"
```

Regex:

`[^\w\s{}]` - Match everything that is not a `\w`, `\s` or a punctuation character.

Comment: I still get the same output. Here it is: `b"[/Very seldom~ will someone enter your life] to questionÃâÂ "` Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue is how I modeled the problem. `tweet` doesn't contain the literal characters `\xc3\xa2...`, it actually encodes them when declaring the string. So the regex is looking for the string `\xc3`, but what `tweet` contains in that position is actually `Ã`

The solution is to encode in utf8 and then convert to string, to finally use regex to get rid of the hex. I got the lead in this post (look the first answer by Martijn Pieters): [python regex: how to remove hex dec characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623464/python-regex-how-to-remove-hex-dec-characters-from-string)