# Discord py limit instead of requirement on range

Tags: discord

I'm having `List index out of range` error and the issue is that I'm trying to show 25 results of players on a squad. Squads don't require 25, but only have a limit of 25. So when the squad doesn't contain 25 players, I get the out of range error. My question is, how do I display a list of squad members up to 25, but not requiring 25? Here is the line that is causing issues:

```
e = discord.Embed(title=f"{x2[0]['squadName']} ({squadnumber})", color=discord.Colour(value=235232), description='\n'.join([f"{c} <@{x[c-1]['player']}> - {int(x[c-1]['points']):,d} Score"]) for c in range(1+(25*(0)), 26+(25*(0)))]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this method to get the range:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [x[i] for i in range(0, 5 if len(x) >= 5 else len(x))]
# this will get the first 5 elements of the list, and if the list isn't long enough
# it will get the length of the list
```

Here's the concept in use:

[image]

And applying this method will get you this:

```py
e = discord.Embed(title=f"{x2[0]['squadName']} ({squadnumber})",
                  color=0x396E0,
                  description='\n'.join([f"{c} <@{x[c-1]['player']}> - {int(x[c-1]['points']):,d} Score" for c in range(1, 26 if len(x.keys()) > 25 else len(x.keys()))]))
```

Also, I noticed another thing with the code, such as `discord.Color(value=some_value)`, you could just do `0xHEXCODE` for example, to get the hex code, so I edited it in to make it easier on the eyes.

Please let me know if you need clarification on anything.

---

**References:**

- [0x usage in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16903228/7808223)
- [Using if/else in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406399/7808223)
- [Getting hex colour codes](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/)